# Performing checks in a makefile

Tags: makefile, installation

I have a makefile with an `install` target which creates a bunch of directories and installs some files. I would also like to check for the existence of a group and if it doesn't exist, create it. To do this I need to make sure the user is running as root. Is there a preferred way to do this in a makefile?

```
install: afile
    # Check user is root, otherwise print error and exit.
    # Check if "auser" exists, otherwise create it.
    # Check if "agroup" exists, otherwise create it.
    install -d -o auser -g agroup -m 0755 /path/to/stuff
    install -o auser -g agroup -m 0644 afile /path/to/stuff/afile
    service start aservice
```

Comment: If you don't mind the non-optimal error message you could just always let the groupadd/useradd fail and terminate the make invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what this has to do with make, really, but I like to use the `id` command for doing these types of checks:

```
[ `id -u` = 0 ] || { echo "Not running as root"; exit 1; }
id "auser" 2>/dev/null || { echo "No user 'auser'"; exit 1; }
```

Checking groups is trickier; I'm actually not sure of a program that will do it.  Of course, you can always just check `/etc/group` directly:

```
grep -q "^agroup:" /etc/groups || { echo "No group 'agroup'"; exit 1; }
```